# Identifying group extension from cohomology class of $D_8$

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, group-cohomology

I have the following problem. It is well known that $H^\ast(D_8,\mathbb{Z}/2)\cong \mathbb{F}_2[x,y,w]/(xy=0)$ with $|x|=|y|=1$ and $|w|=2$ (see Adem,Milgram "Cohomology of finite groups"). So we get that.
$$
H^2(D_8,\mathbb{Z}/2)=\mathbb{F}_2\langle x^2, y^2,w\rangle.
$$

I wanted to ask if there is any method/reference for describing extensions corresponding to particular cohomology classes. I am especially interested in classes $x^2+y^2+w$ and $x^2+w$.

Also, a broader question is - are there any general, or more general, methods of constructing extensions given a class in the second cohomology of a group? Any reference or help would be appreciated.

EDIT: $D_8$ here is the group of symmetries of a square.

Comment: For your second question I suppose it depends how the class is given.  If you have an explicit 2-cocycle then the extension is easy to write down. In your example I suppose you need explicit cocycles for each of the generators

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I see, I firstly posted, then looked through the internet (not the best behaviour). Here is the method: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/group+extension#CentralExtensionClassificationByGroupCohomology

Comment: However, I'm still interested in the question about $D_8$. I suppose that the extensions are already well-studied, so if I can avoid computing cocycles by hand and look into some references, that would be great :)

Comment: Could I just point out that there are two conventions for notation for the dihedral group, and you have not said which one you are using. $D_n$ can denote the dihedral group of order $n$ or of order$2n$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you, that's fair point. Edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a start for your specific questions.  It is easy to see that under the inclusion $C_4 < D_8$, $x$ and $y$ both map to the 1 dimensional class and $w$ maps to the nonzero 2 dimensional class.  So one concludes that a group $P$ of order 16 fitting into a central extension
$$ C_2 \rightarrow P \rightarrow D_8$$
corresponds to an element of $H^2(D_8)$ that involves $w$ if and only if $P$ has a cyclic subgroup of order 8, as $C_8$ is the group fitting into the nontrivial central extension
$$ C_2 \rightarrow C_8 \rightarrow C_4.$$

Checking the wonderful website GroupNames ([https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/index.html](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/index.html)) one sees that there are only three groups of order 16 that both have $D_8$ (called $D_4$ there) as a quotient and $C_8$ as a subgroup: $D_{16}$, $Q_{16}$, and $SD_{16}$.

I think that $w$ corresponds to $D_{16}$ since I think one gets the right cohomology ring. (See another fun website: https://users.fmi.uni-jena.de/cohomology/16web/index.html)  Symmetry considerations make me  then guess that $x^2+y^2+w$ corresponds to $Q_{16}$ and $x^2+w$ corresponds to $SD_{16}$.